# Access to prototype created inside directive link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, prototype

I have this code:

```
angular.module('headroom', []).directive('headroom', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            tolerance: '=',
            offset: '=',
            classes: '=',
            target: '@',
            onPin: '&',
            onUnpin: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
                var options = {};
                angular.forEach(Headroom.options, function(value, key) {
                    options[key] = scope[key] || Headroom.options[key];
                });
                var headroom = new Headroom(element[0], options);
                headroom.init();
                scope.$on('destroy', function() {
                    headroom.destroy();
                });
        }
    };
});
```

How can i access to Headroom prototype (var headroom) from my controller??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend the options as follows

```
var options = {
     onPin: function () {
         console.log('Pin');
     },
     onUnpin: function () {
         console.log('Un Pin');
     }
};
```

from what you had

```
var options = {};
```

when it loops over the options it only has keys for the classes, tolerance and offset. Adding this will give you the callback you need.

Comment: I have also noticed that the default Headroom.options does not include onPin and onUnpin properties.